# Problema ao fazer uma comparacao em Java (Spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

Boa tarde, tenho este código aqui

```
public Pedido alterPedido(Long id, Pedido novoPedido, int operation) {
        Pedido pedido0 = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new PedidoException("Pedido com id '" + id + "' nao encontrado."));

        try {
            Class<?> pedidoClass = Pedido.class;
            Field[] fields = pedidoClass.getDeclaredFields();

            for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                System.out.println("Operation: " + operation);
                if (field.getName().equals("totalPedido") && field.getType() == double.class && operation == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Entrou em total pedido");
                    Object value = field.get(novoPedido);
                    if (value != null) {
                        field.set(pedido0, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            repository.saveAndFlush(pedido0);
            return novoPedido;

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new PedidoException("Erro ao atualizar pedido." + e);
        }

    }
```

Dentro desta funcao, esta entrando respectivamente, **(1, "totalPedido: 150", 12342)**
Dentro do IF, a condicao é, se operation for igual a 2, ele deveria entrar, porém, mesmo com operation *12342* ele entra na condicao porém nao printa o

```
System.out.println("Entrou em total pedido");
```

E eu nao sei por que! Ele esta entrando em `field.set(pedido0, value)` mas nao printa. e tambem nao deveria entrar. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Parece haver uma inconsistência no seu código. Você espera que o bloco if seja executado somente quando operation for igual a 2, mas curiosamente, mesmo quando operation é 12342, o programa parece tratar como se fosse igual a 2, entrando no bloco if sem, contudo, mostrar a mensagem "Entrou em total pedido". Continua ...

Comment: Isso realmente soa contraditório, porque se operation não é 2, o código dentro desse if não deveria rodar, incluindo tanto a impressão da mensagem quanto a execução do field.set. Para resolver isso, considere checar novamente o valor de operation para ter certeza de que não está sendo alterado antes do if.

Comment: Insira comandos de log para imprimir o valor de operation em diversos pontos do método alterPedido, especialmente imediatamente antes do if e no início do método. Isso ajudará a identificar se o valor muda em algum momento durante a execução.

Comment: System.out.println("Valor de operation no início do método: " + operation);


// Outros códigos...

System.out.println("Valor de operation antes do if: " + operation);
if (field.getName().equals("totalPedido") && field.getType() == double.class && operation == 2) {
    // Seu código...
}